# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method '__defineGetter__

Tags: javascript, .net

I am getting the following error when i opened my project in IE9.
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method '**defineGetter**.
How can i solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__defineGetter__` is deprecated:
MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/DefineGetter

For defining getters and setters use `defineProperty`:

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dd548687%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Comment: @Indra Ramasani: check that IE9 runs in standards mode. Reread _Requirements_ section in MSDN link and _Cross-browser concerns_ section in MDN link from answer.